# Add a constraint on the Symfony login form

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I've encountered a new issue on my **Symfony** application and I cannot find anything to help me.

In my database, a user has an `activation_token` field.

When the user creates his account on my website, it generates a random token that will be used to validate his account. It will send him an email with the token in order to verify/activate his account and when he will click on it, it will set the `activation_token` field to `null`.

Creating the account works. Sending the email works. Validating the account works. I only have 1 issue.

I'd like to add a constraint that when the `activation_token` field is not null, the user won't be able to log in. In short, the user will need to validate his account at first in order to be able to log in. But I have no clue how to add a constraint like that.

Currently, I can log in even if I didn't validate my account and that's exactly what I want to prevent.

I haven't created a custom login form in PHP, I'm using the **Security bundle from Symfony**. Here we have a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCMVN.png) of my `security.yaml` file.

I don't know if it's possible to add a constraint with the Security bundle or not.

Comment: Probably need a [custom user checker](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html).  Make sure you select your Symfony version in the docs.

Comment: Thank you, indeed the custom user checker was the solution to my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Cerad's comment to the question:

If you are using Symfony >= 4.4 you can write a custom `UserChecker`. From [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html):

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User as AppUser;
use App\Exception\AccountDeletedException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccountExpiredException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAccountStatusException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
            return;
        }
        
        // this is your custom check:
        if (null !== $user->getActivationToken()) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAccountStatusException('Please validate your account first, before logging in.');
        }
    }

    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        // nothing to check here.
        return;
    }
}
```

Add the user checker to your security configuration like this:

```
# config/packages/security.yaml

# ...
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
```

Comment: So it was that simple  Well, **thank you very much**! I had so much trouble with that. Everything now works fine like I want to 

Answer (score 1):

**For version before Symfony 4.1**

Instead of having your User Entity implementing the basic UserInterface, you can implement AdvancedUserInterface which contains more functions usefull for activating/deactivating user, locking user, expiring user etc

Here is the link of the documentation page: https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security/entity_provider.html#forbid-inactive-users-advanceduserinterface

In your case, you may need to add this kind of logic:

```
public function isEnabled()
{
    return null === $this->validationToken;
}
```

Comment: The AdvancedUserInterface [is deprecated since version 4.1](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-deprecated-the-advanceduserinterface). Instead, the custom user checker seems to be the way to go here, as noted by Cerad in a comment to the question. Eventually it depends on OP's version though.

Comment: Good spot, thanks for pointing out the deprecation

Comment: Yes, the custom user checker was the way to fix my problem. And I'm also using **Symfony 5** so I wouldn't have been able to use the *AdvancedUserInterface*. I'll remember to detail the version I'm using next time. Thank you all for your help 